# cannot import name 'HTMLParseError' from 'html.parser'

Tags: python, namespaces

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
cannot import name 'HTMLParseError' from 'html.parser' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/html/parser.py)
  File "/Users/asantoshkumar/Desktop/untitled folder/&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/asantoshkumar/Desktop/untitled folder/&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap_external&gt;", line 728, in exec_module
  File "/Users/asantoshkumar/Desktop/untitled folder/&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "/Users/asantoshkumar/Desktop/untitled folder/&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "/Users/asantoshkumar/Desktop/untitled folder/&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/asantoshkumar/Desktop/untitled folder/&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/asantoshkumar/Desktop/untitled folder/&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 1043, in _handle_fromlist
```

---

I am getting above error while runing the below lines of code. I have installed all necessary files as per NSEpy documentation. Please help.

Code:

```
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import date
sbin = get_history(symbol="SBIN", start=date(2017,1,1), end=date(2019,1,11))
#data[['Close']].plot()
print(sbin)
```

I have installed NSEpy and all necessary modules through pip3 install command. I am using Mac.

```
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import date
sbin = get_history(symbol="SBIN", start=date(2017,1,1), end=date(2019,1,11))
#data[['Close']].plot() print(sbin)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming it is a compatibility error in which there is something wrong with the module itself. Check if the module is updated or not and if you are running the newest version of both your interpreter and the module. You could have to edit the module itself, which is very time taking. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this lib, but my guess is that your python path is not configured correctly, causing the module to not be either imported or loaded correctly.